# How to get results from query using loop

Tags: php, sql, loops

I'm trying to make a query using procedural PHP. I've used OOP mostly. It's not giving correct results.
I want to get all records from table offers and then make an array width all offer ids in it.

When `print_r($sql->getNumRows())` - it gives me correct count. But I want to put ids in array and when I `print_r(count($all))`  - count is bigger.

What is proper way to do that?

My code is:

```
$sql->query("SELECT id  FROM offers ORDER BY id ASC");
if ($row=$sql->getNumRows()) {
    for ($i=0; $i< $sql->getNumRows(); $i++) { 
        $all[]= $sql->getRow($i);
    }

    print_r($sql->getNumRows()); //this prints correct number
    print_r(count($all)); //this prints bigger count
```

Comment: Are you sure `$all` was empty before this loop?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you aren't using MySQL Improved Extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)?

I believe the way you are trying to do it has been deprecated.  You could try something like this:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT id  FROM offers ORDER BY id ASC";

$allRows = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
        //Store the row in an array for later use
        $allRows[] = $row;
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

print_r(count($allRows));
print_r($allRows);

?>
```